# How to change console font in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio

In Notepad++ it is possible to change the console font (with NppExec plugin).
I changed it to Courier New, so that `arara` output is well aligned:

[image]

Does anybody know if we can do the same in TeXstudio?

[image]

Comment: my texstudio version is a bit outdated and it has no button to call arara, but it looks as if you can change the console font in the option on the "general" page. The change affects the menus too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I created the button to call arara by myself, you can grasp it looking at the icon :) I'll try and let you know.

Comment: To change only the font for the edited text, set it in the `editor` page.

Comment: @Bernard Not the edited text, as you can see I have already change it to have a dark theme. I would like to change the "Message" area font.

Comment: I see. It seems I've misunderstood. Personally, I prefer using Deja Vu Sans Mono (more readable).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, it affects the menu, too. It is annoying :(

Comment: @Bernard Unfortunately, Deja Vu Sans is not an option present in my TeXstudio or my Notepad++

Comment: Can't you install it  system wide?

Comment: @Bernard I don't know how to do it... I'm not an expert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101149/discussion-between-bernard-and-carlatex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are undocumented entries `LogView/FontFamily` and `LogView/FontSize` that you can add to your config file (`texstudio.ini`).

Comment: Works perfectly! I have another question but I'll post it later, thank you very much!

Comment: I've asked a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517182/how-to-change-the-number-of-chars-of-the-console-line, I thank you if you can look at it.